# CAS SSO : which URL link to keep connected using service

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

Having two website requiring cas authentification.
I would like to add a URL link to the second application so that 
if i am already connected , i dont need to put my credential a second time.

How can i get the right syntax ?
How can i find the the path to the target site cas authentification "controller"?

It is something like

```
  https://[cas_server_domain_name]/cas/login?service=https://[a_domain_name]/[and-then?]
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like this work :

```
 https://[my cas_server_domain_name]/cas/login?service=https://[my other casified website domain name]
```